# Ansible cannot find required boto3 module

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto3

I am having trouble to fix a seemingly simple issue. I am missing a plugin during execution of an ansible playbook from a git repository. It is trying to execute the Ansible ec2_group_info command from AWS boto3 plugin. The error is the following:

```
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/home/user/git-repo-name/plugins/filters/kms_filters.py) as it seems to 
be invalid: No module named 'boto3'
failed: [localhost] (item=DEV) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item":
"DEV", "msg": "boto3 required for this module"}
```

My ansible information using ansible --version inside of the repo folder locally looks like this:

```
ansible 2.9.6
config file = /home/user-name/repo-name/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/home/user-name/repo-name/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Outside of the repo folder locally it looks like this:

```
ansible 2.9.6
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/home/user-name/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Python 3 is installed as well as boto3 globally, and I can use boto3 properly using python3.
I have searched on many forum pages, but I could not find a satisfying solution to my issue ...

To me it seems like it does not search for all the possible installed plugin options globally but only restrained to the options of the repo...

It seems to be failing to find the module in this plugin kms_filters.py as well. The content of the file is the following:

```
import boto3
import base64

kms = boto3.client('kms', region_name='region-name')

def kms_decrypt(ciphertext):
    return kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(ciphertext)).get('Plaintext')

def kms_encrypt(plaintext, key):
    return base64.b64encode(kms.encrypt(KeyId=key,Plaintext=plaintext).get('CiphertextBlob'))

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return { 'kms_encrypt': kms_encrypt, 'kms_decrypt': kms_decrypt }
```

How would I need to configure it so that it can find the boto3 plugin? Where do I need to add any information that makes this possible??? If possible I would prefer if the plugin is available to be used within the repo configuration itself.

Comment: Remember that ansible modules depend on the Python installation of the remote (target) host, not your local host. What does your playbook look like? Are you targeting a remote host? Is `boto3` installed there?

Comment: What larsks said is 100% true, but also unless you have **credentials** on the remote machine, 90% of the time the use of those cloud tasks has `delegate_to: localhost` or even just has the whole playbook as `hosts: localhost` since there's nothing that's going to be magic about ssh-ing into a machine just to run a cloud module

Comment: I don't understand how you mean this? I try to retrieve information from AWS using an ansible plugin. I do not try to perform any tasks on a remote host directly. How should this affect my script? Should it not use the local settings of my own machine to perform this task?

Comment: Well your understanding is wrong, then. As pointed by @larsks, Ansible ships your tasks as Python executable to your remote nodes, then your remote nodes are using their own Python interpreter to execute them. So, yes you do need those dependancies in your remote nodes. The good thing is: [you can write an Ansible task to install the missing packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) prior to doing any other task.

Comment: Does that mean that it would be enough to simply add a task to install boto3 through pip in ansible prior to executing ec2_group_info to allow that ansible can find boto3 during execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, You might be having multiple python versions, My guess is your python3 soft link points to python3.6 .Please run `ls -lrt python*` in /usr/bin directory to identify the python3 version. It is likely that you installed boto3 for a different python version.

Suggest try running installation of boto3 using ansible pre_tasks. That way your boto3 will always be present.

Comment: Installing boto3 prior also works it for me, thanks a lot!